# Creating a function which only accepts positive Integer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, int

I am trying to create a public function which only accepts positive integer.And I cant think of any ways to do it. Even if I were to check the value and return the error, how should I go about?
My current code is:

```
public func encodeQuantity(value: Int) -> String {

// Besides using if-else to check, is there any alternatives?
    if value < 0 {
        return "Negative values are not supported" << I dont know how we should return an error here to the user when using our function but putting a negative number
    } else {
        return "\(value+10)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Define the parameter as `UnsignedInteger`, let the language do the work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Int` supports negative numbers. Instead, only support arguments that can't represent negative numbers.

The [UnsignedInteger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsignedinteger) protocol is adopted by 5 standard library types:

- `UInt` (same as `UInt64`)
- `UInt32`
- `UInt16`
- `UInt8`

```swift
public func encodeQuantity(value: some UnsignedInteger) -> String {
  "\(value + 10)"
}
```

An example using a `UInt`:

```swift
encodeQuantity(value: 25 as UInt) // "35"
```

Comment: it solved my problem. Thank you! wondering if UInt and Int works the same way now

Comment: @L.William When you ask if they work the same, in what respect do you mean, exactly? Clearly they don't entirely work the same, `Int` supports negative numbers, and `UInt` doesn't, but has a maximum value that's twice as large.

Comment: Jessy did a detailed explaination. Thanks alot guys!